# Rewrite Specific URL to Another Specific URL

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I recently upgraded a Joomla installation to 1.7. Due to this the linking system is now different.  My client has a FLASH banner with specific links inside the FLASH and no access to the original .fla for editing.

What I would like to do is rewrite the linked URL from the banner to what the article id is.

I have the following in my .htaccess but it's not redirecting, I get a 404 error.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=25$ index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=25&Itemid=59 [L]
```

Thanks! I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't match query_strings in RewriteRule, you have to use the %{QUERY_STRING} variable in a RewriteCond, like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^option=com_content&view=article&id=25$
RewriteRule ^index.php$ index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=25&Itemid=59 [L]
```